# What are the risks / factors to watch when setting a high maxPoolSize with JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection-pooling, amazon-rds

My application is a [Piwik Server](https://piwik.org/) that receives incoming tracking data from tracking codes placed on hundreds of websites.  The bulk of the workload is small writes to the database hundreds of times per second as these tracking requests come in.  I'm using MySQL server with JDBC and Hibernate.

I've recently been increasing the maxPoolSize setting gradually on my application to improve performance.  It certainly seems like the higher I set the configuration, the more responsive the application is, and the more stable the disk queue depth.

My current configuration:

```
jdbc.maxPoolSize=100
jdbc.minPoolSize=100
jdbc.maxStatements=1000
```

Essentially, my question is what risks I should be watching for when I increase the maxPoolSize?  Are there any specific factors or metrics that I should watch to judge whether I've configured this setting too high?  Obviously if increasing the maxPoolSize was a magic bullet for resolving performance problems, everyone would want to set it as high as possible.  Apologies in advance if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find any answer addressing how to assess if your connection pool is **too large**.

I'm running MySQL on an AWS RDS instance. These are my guesses as to what the concerns might be:

- Avoid exceeding the maximum number of connections allowed by the RDS instance type
- Would an excessively high setting suck up all the memory on the server and impact performance?
- Will too many threads cause tables to lock and increase queue time for some of the queries?

Any assistance in understanding what factors to watch for would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly recommend setting up [DropWizard metrics](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Dropwizard-Metrics) and/or [JMX monitoring](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/MBean-(JMX)-Monitoring-and-Management).

In the case of JMX, graph the "Active Connections" over time, if your pool never crosses (or rarely crosses) a given threshold, setting the maximumPoolSize above that is simply wasting resources.

In the case of DropWizard metrics, the "Usage" measurement -- reflecting how long connections are out of the pool -- would give a "comparable" for you to check when playing with the *maximumPoolSize*.

If connections tend to be out of the pool longer when the *maximumPoolSize* is `50` (for example) compared to `40`, that would indicate that the database is oversaturated, and `40` is closer to ideal.

If there is no difference between a *maximumPoolSize* of `30` compared to `40` (again, just an example), it *could* mean that `40` is simply unnecessarily high, ***or*** it could mean that the period of time over which those metrics were collected was simply a low period of demand and `40` may still be correct.

Best of all is to combine the above metrics with total web request service times and overlay them on a graph or at least side-by-side.

Metrics are the key to analysis!  Find and track as many relevant ones as you can; patterns will emerge.
[image]
Lastly, you might try setting the pool for `minumumIdle=20` and `maximumPoolSize=100` and see where the pool *generally* settles, ignoring the occasional spike.  RDS is unlike typical databases, where you control the hardware where the database is running.  With RDS you really don't know how Amazon is spreading the load, so it is just going to require experimentation.  Let each experiment run long enough (several hours) to collect sufficient data, and take screenshots of your monitor for comparison.

Comment: Thanks, I especially appreciate the tool suggestions.  The advice to experiment with where the pool settles makes sense too.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Avoid exceeding the maximum number of connections allowed by the RDS instance type.

That is plausible.

> Would an excessively high setting suck up all the memory on the server and impact performance?

That is possible.  Each active connection in the pool will have associated buffers, etcetera.  However I would expect the buffers to be bounded.

> Will too many threads cause tables to lock and increase queue time for some of the queries?

Possibly.  However, if you are mostly doing small writes then I'd not have thought that locking would be a concern for other writes.  But if you are doing simultaneous queries that entail a table scan, locking could be a concern.

---

However, I'd not have thought that increasing the pool size (above 100) is likely to increase throughput.  Check the CPU and/or disk I/O load on the database instance, or network traffic between your front end and the DB instance.  If the database is where the bottleneck is, then allowing the front end to make more simultaneous requests is likely to make performance worse.

You need to consider what happens if the load (e.g. request rate) on your system goes above the overall throughput that it can sustain.  If the pool size is too large, then the front-end load spike could turn into a database load-spike that leads to a *drop* in throughput.  The problem is that you won't know when the load spike is going to happen, and unless you have **load tested** your system beforehand with the tweaked pool size, you won't know what the (actual) affect of the pool size change will be ...